# How to add web part (lvwp) programatically in SP2010?

Tags: web-part

How do I add web part on publishing pages. The publishing pages are in Pages list. I like to add the built in contact web part. Also like to add few web part and backend of these web part are list sitting inside the same web.

Comment: Is this SP2007 way? using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages; 
SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
SPList list = web.Lists["List Name"];
SPFile webPartPage = web.Files["default.aspx"]; //or web.GetFile() depending on where the page is
SPLimitedWebpartManager webpartManager = webPartPage.GetLimitedWebPartManager(System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalisationScope.Shared);
ListViewWebPart wp = new ListViewWebPart();
wp.ListName = list.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
wp.ViewGuid = list.Views["View name"].ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
weppartManager.AddWebPart(wp, "Zone name", 0);

Comment: Roxanne: This is the second time you've done this - did you mean to edit your post and add that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SPWeb web = ...
PublishingWeb pWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);
PublishingPage page = pWeb.GetPublishingPage(<pageUrl>);
SPFile file = page.ListItem.File;
SPLimitedWebPartManager mgr = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
mgr.AddWebPart(<webPart>, <zoneId>, <zoneIndex>);
```

Do not forget to dispose where it is necessary.

Comment: Actually, I want to add the build in WP thats in wp gallery "contact details" or contactwp.dwp